# recursive function with memo

Tags: javascript, recursion, indexing

I am having trouble trying to return from this recursive function. I have an undex of key value pairs that points to more single letter characters and so on. This seems to be working but I am definitely dropping results that should be being collected.

Can any one see anything obvious that may be a problem?

```
 lunr.TokenStore.prototype.sub_roots = function(first_key,root,memo){
      memo = memo || {}
          for(var key in root){
            if(first_key === key) {
                memo[first_key] = root[key]
                memo["docs"] = root[key].docs || {}
                //return memo
            }
            if( key !== 'docs' ) { this.sub_roots(first_key,root[key],memo) }
          }
            return memo
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first_key is always the same and memo is an {} instead of an array

Comment: and the commented out return memo should be continue